# Chrome extension to Firefox extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon

I have developed a Chrome extension
On Chrome everything works as I expect

I am now trying to migrate the extension to Firefox

It tells me that the developed extension is compatible with Firefox (I used this link https://www.extensiontest.com/)

However, I have some problems
I have a devtools_script ("VariableGrid.js") which sends messages to the ContentScript via chrome.tabs.query

```
chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true }, function (tabs) {
chrome.tabs.sendMessage(chrome.devtools.inspectedWindow.tabId, { from: "FromExample", message: "MessageExample" }, (response) => {
......
});
});
```

My ContentScript replies to the message like this

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
(request, sender, sendResponse) => {
......
});
```

On Firefox chrome.tabs is undefined
I tried using browser.tabs but it's the same

I read that tabs can only be used on background script

Why does this work on my Chrome extension and not on Firefox?

If I tried to move that piece of code to the background script I would still have a problem:

> chrome.devtools.inspectedWindow.tabId is undefined

my Manifest is like this

```
 {
  "browser_specific_settings": {
    "gecko": {
      "id": "addon@example.com",
      "strict_min_version": "42.0"
    }
  },
  "name": "xxxx",
  "description": "xxxx",  
  "version": "0.0.0.1",
  "browser_action": {
      "default_popup": "Popup.html"
  },
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "background": {
    "scripts":["jquery.min.js", "background.js"],
    "persistent": true
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
      "js": ["jquery.min.js", "Content.js"]
    }
  ],  
  "web_accessible_resources": [
    "Content.js"
  ],
  "devtools_page": "Devtools.html",
  "permissions": [
    "webRequest",
    "webRequestBlocking",
        "tabs",
        "activeTab",
        "notifications",
        "storage",
        "http://*/",
        "https://*/",
        "<all_urls>"
  ]
}
```

Comment: `Why does this work on my Chrome extension and not on Firefox?` to properly answer that, one would need to see the whole extension, including manifest and all code

Comment: Logging `chrome.tabs` in a regular <script> yields undefined, so if definitely only exists in the context of a background script. (I'm commenting primarily on the very last part of your question, which suggests you think your background script is a foreground one) In a background script, `browser.tabs` should absolutely work.

Comment: Stupid question: have you actually tried to run your code as-is in Firefox? Since Mozilla itself is telling you that should work?

Comment: I added the code and the manifest to the question @Bravo

Comment: @ChrisG i tried but the messages are not sent, debugging i saw that the problem is that chrome.tabs is undefined, even replacing it with browser.tabs i have the same problem